# EU DCC/covid restrictions and layovers

Tags: air-travel, layovers, covid-19, eu

Countries, such as Spain, Italy or Greece, have opened their borders to vaccinated travelers from selected countries. Other EU countries may have not.
How do layovers work now? If one were to fly through a country that would not allow them entry, but only on thejr way to one that does, would the airline allow them to board?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.